# Where do I need to save javascript files for Node.js in windows 8

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows-8

I have JUST downloaded node.js and am having to work with their command line for the first time. It appears that every tutorial on the planet gives the same starter app.
It uses the code...
    var http = require('http');

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8124);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

and wants me to save it to the file example.js.
The file can then be run by typing...

```
node example.js
```

but all the command line gives me is

> ...

The tutorials do not say WHERE I should save the file. To my C drive? To the same file as node.js? Anywhere?
I have tried all three and they don't seem to work. If there is any other solution, or simply something else I should be looking into and asking about, that help would be appreciated too. But at this point I honestly have no idea what the problem is, and there appears to be very few resources to help me here.

Answer (score 3):

When you run `node example.js` from your prompt, it's assuming that `example.js` is in the current working directory.

To change your current working directory, use the change directory (`cd`) command:

```
cd C:\Projects\MyProject
node example.js
```

This is equivalent to

```
node C:\Projects\MyProject\example.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct! you can save it any where and change to that directory by the (cd) command on node.js command prompt which will then give message says: "Server running at: 127.0.0.1:8124.
So point your browser to that address and you see your file.